# electron-windows-store return error: unknown option `--flatten'

Tags: electron, moodle

I have tried to make desktop exe for window using electron. I have run below command to generate sign version of exe:

```
electron-windows-store --input-directory .\\desktop\\dist\\win-unpacked --output-directory .\\desktop\\store --flatten true -a .\\resources\\desktop -m .\\desktop\\assets\\windows\\AppXManifest.xml --package-version 0.0.0.1 --package-name MoodleDesktop
```

But it give me below error:

```
> moodledesktop@3.5.1 windows.store D:\wamp64\www\moodle-desktop
> electron-windows-store --input-directory .\desktop\dist\win-unpacked --output-directory .\desktop\store --flatten true -a .\resources\desktop -m .\desktop\assets\windows\AppXManifest.xml --package-version 0.0.0.1 --package-name MoodleDesktop

You need at least Node 4.x to run this script
error: unknown option `--flatten'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! moodledesktop@3.5.1 windows.store: `electron-windows-store --input-directory .\desktop\dist\win-unpacked --output-directory .\desktop\store --flatten true -a .\resources\desktop -m .\desktop\assets\windows\AppXManifest.xml --package-version 0.0.0.1 --package-name VedificDesktop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the moodledesktop@3.5.1 windows.store script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\prawez.musharraf\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-12T09_50_34_214Z-debug.log
```

How we resolve this error??

Any help really appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as from sep 2018 the option flatten been removed
https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-store/commit/dcc654df2ec2bb706dc4f1664aa4775ab320541e

that mean just remove it from the command and everything going to be okay!